# Existence of two natural number satisfying a given condition in a given set

Tags: elementary-number-theory, natural-numbers

Suppose $A=\{1,2,\dots,112\}$, $B \subset A$ and the number of elements in $B$ is greater or equal to 37. Then, is it true that there always exist two elements $x,y \in B$ such that $x-y\in \{9,10,19\}$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint:  The fact that $9+10=19$ is very relevant to this problem.

Comment: Hint to prove or disprove?

Comment: Well, the way the problem was structured, I thought it would be relevant, but apparently you can prove the statement is true with any triple of forbidden differences in this case.

Comment: Well, the way the problem is structured, I would tend to think it's true.  But I need to check the details.  (Until then, scratch my last comment.)

Comment: Here's my reasoning as I go along.  See if any of this helps.  There are $111$ possible differences that can be formed by the difference of two numbers in $A$, and $37\choose 2$ ways of picking $x_i,x_j\in A$ with $x_i<x_j$.

Comment: I am thinking along with you. thanks

Comment: Well, how about this?  If $x$ is chosen, then $x+9$, $x+10$, and $x+19$ are all forbidden.  This means that only $\frac{1}{4}$ of the numbers of $A$ can appear, EXCEPT that we have overcounted the forbidden numbers.  For example, if our $37$ numbers we choose includes $1$ and $2$, then we are counting $11$ as forbidden twice (as $11-2$ and $11-1$).  So it boils down to bounding the overcount ...

Comment: This directions seem helpful.

Comment: Let's assume we have the set $\{x_1,\dots,x_{37}\}$ for which we are able to avoid $9,10,19$ as differences.  Assume $x_i<x_j$ for $i<j$. We've established already that $x_i+a$ cannot occur in this set for all $i$ and all $a\in\{9,10,19\}$.  How many times did we overcount? The overcounts would have totake the form $x_i+19=x_j+9$, $x_i+19=x_j+10$, and $x_i+10=x_j+9$.  Now $x_i+19=x_j+9$ implies $x_j-x_i=10$ which cannot occur by our choice.  Similarly, $x_i+19=x_j+10$ implies $x_j-x_i=9$, so again we're safe.  That leaves us with $x_i+10=x_j+9$.  More in a bit ...

Comment: This means that $x_j=x_i+1$.

Comment: That's true.  There's still a way to go, and my brain is slowing down due to the late hour :(

Comment: Yes it is. I am very happy that you help me and i am very thankful for your help. I will try to solve it in this direction. If i could find the solution, then i will notify you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check tomorrow.  Good luck :-)

Comment: Good morning.  Not elegant, but you should be able to show that there are at most $9$ elements of $A_{[1,28]}=\{1,2,\dots,28\}$ that satisfy $a-b\ne 9,10,19$ for all $a,b\in A_{[1,28]}$.  Same for $A_{[29,56]}$,  $A_{[57,84]}$, and  $A_{[85,112]}$.  This gives an upper bound of $36$, showing that a difference of $9,10$ or $19$ can be attained if $37$ numbers are chosen from $A$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will write it down nicely.

Comment: I regret that the last part is so inelegant.  It may take quite a few cases.  I'll still be thinking about an elegant proof and I will post if I find one.  I nay case, good luck with your education!

Comment: Finally, I found a fairly decent way to present the proof :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's prove the following ...

**Claim**: Let $S$ be a subset of $X=\{1,2,\dots , 28\}$ for which $a-b\not\in\{9,10,19\}$ for all $a,b\in S$.  Then $|S|\le 9$.

By way of contradiction, assume that $|S|\ge 10$.  Now arrange the elements of $X$ as follows.

\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrr}
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&\\
10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19\\
20&21&22&23&24&25&26&27&28&
\end{array}

Note that $S$ can contain at most one element from each column.  However, as $|S|\ge 10$, $S$ must contain at least one element from every column.  In particular, $19\in S$ is forced.

Now consider the following arrangement of the elements of $X$.

\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrr}
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\
11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19\\
20&21&22&23&24&25&26&27&28&
\end{array}

By using the exact same reasoning as above, we see that $10\in S$ is forced.  But this is a contradiction because $19-10=9$.  Thus $|S|\le 9$ as claimed.

We may repeat this argument on the three remaining subintervals $\{29,\dots,56\}$, $\{57,\dots,84\}$, and $\{85,\dots,112\}$.  This shows there are at most $9+9+9+9=36$ elements of $\{1,2,\dots,112\}$ with the desired avoidance property.  Hence $|A|\ge 37$ will force the difference of some pair of elements of $A$ to be $9$, $10$ or $19$.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is a very nice one.

Comment: Any time.  I will definitely be conscious of your posts in the future.  It was a real pleasure to work with you.

Comment: It is very kind of you. Again i should say thank you so much.